# Custom Domains in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, vhosts

I've got a vhosts file set up for my local machine where I use a made up domain (cascade.mtn) with a bunch of subdomains (rainier.cascade.mtn, hood.cascade.mtn, etc). In every other browser I can hit those domains just fine but in Chrome it just takes me to a Google search.

Is there anyway to force Chrome to recognized the cascade.mtn domain?

Comment: Also, the first entry in my vhosts file is the rainier.cascade.mtn domain, and Chrome can load that one. So maybe it's something with the vhosts file? But that would affect other browsers too I assume.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old question, but posting answer since I ran into the same thing.

If you add a trailing slash (`/`) to the end of the URL, it will hint Chrome to treat it as a URL, which is what you want. From that point, it will 'learn' that that is indeed a valid URL and you won't require the trailing slash anymore.

Comment: You're welcome :D I was migrating to chrome myself and this was going to be a deal breaker, so I asked around on the dev IRC channel.

Comment: what if my application does resolve paths with trailing slash differently than the ones without? your solution doesnt work for me